# Print $entity info

Tags: 7, entities

This may be a rookie question, but the docs are quite broad, and im looking for a simple answer.

I am using dpm($entity) to view the entity object, and it gives me the following...

[image]

Now I want to access these values in a computed field, I have tried...

```
$id = $entity=>id;
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

and...

```
$id = $entity["id"];
```

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Entity as array

Can someone tell me what Im doing wrong?

Comment: It's $entity->id

Comment: This is a plain PHP question. `$entity` is an object, and PHP has only a way to access its fields. Drupal doesn't change PHP syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `->` operator for accessing the data attributes in a PHP object.

Use `$entity->id` to access the id of the entity.

If you want to access a value of the field (which is an array), you do it like
`$entity->field_field_name['und'][0]['value']` depending on the type of field.

Comment: Maybe you want to also briefly add to that what the "0" stands for? And/or the "und"?